# object initializer - setting field to other field doesn't work as expected, why?

Tags: c#, linq

I had some code that looked like this:

```
List<ListBoxItem> items = (
    from String file in e.Result
    select new ListBoxItem {
        Content = file.Split('\\').Last(),
        Tag = Content,
    }).ToList<ListBoxItem>();
```

Here, after object creation, the result is not equivalent to

```
List<ListBoxItem> items = (
    from String file in e.Result
    select new ListBoxItem {
        Content = file.Split('\\').Last(),
        Tag = file.Split('\\').Last(),
    }).ToList<ListBoxItem>();
```

Why are the resulting object initializations different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have `Content` declared in the enclosing scope, your code is not even legal.  You cannot refer to other properties of the object you are initializing while in the middle of initializing it.

Comment: Good catch, I had no idea what he was getting at

Comment: Yep. The order of initialization is unspecified, although in practice I believe the members are initialized in the order they are declared in their class.

Comment: well, that was dumb. I do have it declared elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Kirk's answer is correct.  However, I think what you're trying to do is being more dry with your code.  I think this is what you're looking to do:

```
List<ListBoxItem> items = (from String file in e.Result
                                       let lastFile = file.Split('\\').Last()
                                       select new ListBoxItem
                                           {
                                               Content = lastFile,
                                               Tag = lastFile
                                           }).ToList<ListBoxItem>();
```

Comment: awesome, I had no idea you could do that

Answer (score 4):

In the line:

```
Tag = Content,
```

The `Content` there is not, AFAIK, relating to the `.Content` of the new object; that expression is resolved in the context of the rest of the code. Are you sure you don't have a `.Content` property/field kicking around? i.e. the equivalent of:

```
var tmp = Content;
select new ListBoxItem
{
    Content = file.Split('\\').Last(),
    Tag = tmp,
}).ToList<ListBoxItem>()
```